# Capybara results in a no method error when its methods are referenced by Rspec

Tags: rspec, capybara, ruby-on-rails-4

**Gem file**

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.0.0'

# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'sqlite3'

# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.0'

# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'

# Use CoffeeScript for .js.coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'

# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'

# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'

# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 1.2'

group :doc do
  # bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
  gem 'sdoc', require: false
end

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano', group: :development

# Use debugger
# gem 'debugger', group: [:development, :test]

gem "factory_girl_rails"

group :development, :test do
  gem "rspec-rails", "~> 2.0"
  gem "capybara", "~> 2.1.0"
end
```

**spec_helper.rb**

```
# This file is copied to spec/ when you run 'rails generate rspec:install'
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
require 'rspec/rails'
require 'rspec/autorun'
require 'capybara/rspec'
require 'capybara/rails'

# Requires supporting ruby files with custom matchers and macros, etc,
# in spec/support/ and its subdirectories.
Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each { |f| require f }

# Checks for pending migrations before tests are run.
# If you are not using ActiveRecord, you can remove this line.
ActiveRecord::Migration.check_pending! if defined?(ActiveRecord::Migration)

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include Capybara::DSL
  # ## Mock Framework
  #
  # If you prefer to use mocha, flexmock or RR, uncomment the appropriate line:
  #
  # config.mock_with :mocha
  # config.mock_with :flexmock
  # config.mock_with :rr

  # Remove this line if you're not using ActiveRecord or ActiveRecord fixtures
  config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"

  # If you're not using ActiveRecord, or you'd prefer not to run each of your
  # examples within a transaction, remove the following line or assign false
  # instead of true.
  config.use_transactional_fixtures = true

  # If true, the base class of anonymous controllers will be inferred
  # automatically. This will be the default behavior in future versions of
  # rspec-rails.
  config.infer_base_class_for_anonymous_controllers = false

  # Run specs in random order to surface order dependencies. If you find an
  # order dependency and want to debug it, you can fix the order by providing
  # the seed, which is printed after each run.
  #     --seed 1234
  config.order = "random"
end
```

**xxtests_spec.rb**

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "Xxtests" do
    describe "GET /xxtests" do
       it "works! (now write some real specs)" do
        get 'people/new'
        response.status.should be(200)
       end
       it "works! (now write some real specs)" do
        get people_path
        response.status.should be(200)
       end
    end

    describe "POST /persons" do
        # visit 'people/new'
        response.status.should be(200)
    end
end
```

All works perfectly. The second I uncomment

```
visit 'people/new'
```

I get

```
undefined method error.
```

I have read the Capybara and Rspec documentation through very carefully, and I've done everything. I really don't know what else to say, but it just does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `visit` inside a `describe` block instead of within a code example (`it` block). Try:

```
describe "POST /persons" do
  it "responds with success status" do      
    visit 'people/new'
    response.status.should be(200)
  end
end
```

The Capybara methods are mixed into instances of the code examples so are not available outside.